# Split step Fourier method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-calculus

I am trying to use  the split-step Fourier (SSF) method  for solving partial differential equation
$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} =u^*f(x,t)+\hat{H}\, u(x,t) \tag{1}$$
The first term causes problems.  As you can see, the equation cannot be written in the form
$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} =\hat{L}\, u(x,t) \tag{2}$$

I can rewrite eq.(1) as
$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} =\left[f(x,t)\frac{u^*(x,t)}{u(x,t)}+\hat{H}\right] u(x,t) \tag{3}$$

Can I still use the SSF method? Will the method remain stable as before? Maybe there are more non-trivial ways to solve this problem?

Comment: What do $u^{*}$ and $\hat{H}$ denote?

Comment: Try rewriting your equation explicitly for real and imaginary parts of u. Then looking formally at the resulting system of equations and checking if you can apply the method

Comment: mattos: $u^*$ conjugate of $u$. $\hat H=-\partial_{xx}+V(x,t)$
 
Yuriy S:  the problem will remain